# Removing all tags (html,script,DOCTYPE) from a page and loading another page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is my problem.  I am throwing a $.post request on a page which returns an error message if the login was unsuccessful and returns me the homepage if login was successful.

What I am trying here is to remove the entire contents of the page including the   and  tags and replace them with the new content that i just received from the $.post request (The post request is a normal page with all the tags intact).

Is this possible by using jQuery?  If not, can it be done by pure javascript?

Comment: Why not just link to the new page? What's the advantage of your approach?

Comment: The only thing you're avoiding here is the url replacement in the browser's adressbar. And perhaps a click sound.. There are different ways to do that, like server side. Please don't look for complicated answers on simple problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still looking for some way to do it by jQuery but I did manage to do it by the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        var uname = $("#uname").val();
        var pword = $("#pword").val();
        var qstring = '?op=login&uname='+uname+'&pword='+pword;
        $.post(document.URL, qstring, function(data){
            //as my script returns the whole new page...
            document.open();
            document.write(data);
            document.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that:

```
$('html').empty()
```

would work to remove all the content; but obviously this comes with the caveat that you'll have to have a *full* html page to insert. You could, possible, use:

```
$(newPageVariableFromAjax).insertAfter($('html').eq(0));
$('html').eq(0).remove(); // or .empty()
```

But I'm not sure this is the best approach you could be using. Why not just empty the body tag, and append the new `body` contents there?

Comment: Ok then how i should fill the new data?

Comment: That includes the scripts? css?

Comment: @Caspar, it does; I've edited with *one* possible way of handling the problem. Though I'm not sure if jQuery can, possibly, remove the document from which it's operating. Or if, or for how long, it can work simply from the browser's memory...it seems a weird request to me, personally.

Comment: Yes it does include everything also script and css

Comment: @LoneWOLFs: in which case, why not just link to the page? Your approach seems needlessly complex.